# How can I combine checking if a string exists with the ? operator?

Tags: javascript

My server name can be one of these:

```
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:3048"
var baseUrl = "http://www.example.org"
var baseUrl = "https://secure.example.org:443"
```

I want the variable server to equal "" if the baseUrl does not contain the word localhost and to equal "localhost" if it contains that word.

Is there a way I can do this with a single line of code?

Comment: Have you checked out indexOf method of String class ? If not, take a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ternary operator and `indexOf()`

```
var server = baseUrl.indexOf('localhost') > -1 ? 'localhost' : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work too, but not sure about browser compatibility for `.includes()` method,

`var host = baseUrl.includes('localhost')? 'localhost' : '';`